# Userform - Find Intersection of row and variable column reference

Tags: userform, intersection

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction (first timer so please be patient with me). I'm ok at mixing and matching bits of code but I'm struggling to find something that meets my specific needs.

I'm creating a spreadsheet for a works project that involves searching for a record and entering data via a userform. I have a table with column headers Code, Lot, Interval 1, Interval 2, Interval 3 etc. and so far I have the following code (adapted from another forum) that returns a row number of the matched Code & Lot userform entries:

```
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim strFirst As String
Dim strCode As String
Dim strLot As String
strGEM = TextBox1.Value
strLot = TextBox2.Value
Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find(strCode, Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    strFirst = rngFound.Address
    Do
        If LCase(Cells(rngFound.row, "B").Text) = LCase(strLot) Then
            'Found a match
            MsgBox "Found a match at: " & rngFound.row & Chr(10)
        End If
        Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find(strCode, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
    Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
End If

Set rngFound = Nothing
```

What I'd like to do is find the intersection of the found row and a column reference entered in a 3rd userform text box (i.e. column header names Interval 1, Interval 2 etc). From there I'm hoping I should be able to get the data entry part figured out.

Thanks for any help you can give, and apologies if I'm not making enough sense.

Alun